# ng-bootstrap accordion title no underline on hover-effect

Tags: css, angular, hover, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngb-accordions in my angular4 app. One accordion should always be opened. My only problem is that I am not able to remove the underline on hovering.
Here is my html-code:

```
<template ngbPanelTitle>
    <span class="no-hover-and-no-cursor-effect">Version</span>
</template>
```

and this is my css-code:

```
.no-hover-and-no-cursor-effect:hover {
  cursor: default;
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

the color works, it stays the same. The cursor also works, but the title is still underlined...

Answer (score 0):

My app is also Angular. The following approach works for me by updating the component's SCSS file:

```css
// overwrite ngb-accordion default ngbPanelTitle styles
:host ::ng-deep {
    .accordion {
        .btn-link {
            color: #666666;
            &:hover,
            &:focus,
            &.focus {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```